# SharePoint 2010 Version History inaccessible in Word 2016

Tags: 2016, office, version-history

We are having an issue with our SharePoint 2010 environment. We recently upgraded from Word 2010 to 2016. After the upgrade, the ability to access version history from within Word has been lost. The history pane shows blank and under Review->Compare any of the options produce an error: "Versions cannot be accessed at this time because the server is busy.". Version histories are accessible from the Web without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2016 does anything show up when you go to File > History? Although I'm trying this in SharePoint 2013. A panel should open up inside word with all your version history information.

[image]

Comment: Yes there is no information under history, even though version history appears in Word 2010 or on the actual site.

Comment: Did you mean to say in your Word 2016? From your original post I thought you upgraded from 2010 to 2016?

Comment: I tested it on my 2010 SharePoint site and your right it does not display history inside word 2016. Looks like the browser is the only place you can view and access this information. Sorry